# asp.net detect DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged after Button Click (JS disabled)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, selectedindexchanged, javascript

I have a DropDownList which is connected to a TextBox. When the event SelectedIndexChanged is fired, the text in the Textbox changes. The content of the textbox can also be changed by user input. At the end of the page the user has to submit the data (button). 
When javascript is enabled everything works fine, but I have also users where javascript is disabled.
Without javascript the SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList gets called after the Button-Click (before the Click-Event of the button is processed). The user input to the textbox gets overwritten by the SelectedIndexChanged event.

How can I detect in Code behind if the SelectedIndexChanged event was triggerd by the button click? How can I get the text of the textbox changed by the user?

EDIT:
Can I use the property IsPostBackEventControlRegistered? This always seems to be true when I click the button, but is false in SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Plain and simple, you can't. Javascript is what enables the webforms magic ajax to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it IS possible, but not easy.  You would essentially need to track whether javascript is enabled by using a hidden field, do something like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="JSEnabled" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Status" Value="F" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForJavaScript() {
        $("#JSEnabled").val("T");
    }
</script>
```

You call this script from window.onload or jquery.ready event, whatever JS option you like, and this can tell you whether you have JS enabled to do the selectedindexchanged event, or if a button triggered it because JS wasn't enabled.  To tell whether the button was clicked and caused the postback, you can check the:

```
Request.Form.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
```

Field and see if the ID matches the UniqueID of the button.  Every control in ASP.NET sets its ID (usually, but not always, for certain reasons) here.  Although, I'm not sure, you may have to set `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` for that to happen.  A hidden field can be manipulated, so it's not fullproof.

The question you should ask is do you really need that complexity?

Comment: I only want to avoid that the user input to the textbox gets overwritten by the event. Maybe the easiest way to achieve this is to implement the connection between the DropDownList and the Textbox with the javascript onchange function instead of using SelectedIndexChanged.